# 10+ ls commands running on a single cron task?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ls

I have the following command running on cron:

```
sudo find "$VOLUME1" "$VOLUME2" "$VOLUME3" "$VOLUME4" -type f -exec ls -lT {} + > $FILE
```

This command takes a couple hours to complete, as it's running over about million files or so.

When I do the `top` command, it shows 14(!!) difference instances of `ls` running. Is this a bug in the script, or what is causing so many ls commands to be running?

Comment: Is your cron schedule running a new instance of the command before it stop the last one?

Comment: It could be...but it runs only once every five hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the length of the command line is limited, `find` cannot start a single `ls` instance with over a million parameters. It will instead spawn multiple `ls` processes with thousands of parameters each.

The maximum command line length seems to be 2097152 on my machine, perhaps that could also be about the size of 1000000/14 filenames?

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, so in the command above, a file would constitute a parameter to be passed to ls?